# How to save a pandas dataframe as csv in azure container

Tags: python, azure

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient

# Connect to the storage account
conn_str = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={storage_account_name};AccountKey={storage_account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str)

# Check if the container exists, if not create it

# Create the folder (blob) inside the container
folder_blob_name = f"{folder_name}/"
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name=folder_blob_name)
if not blob_client.exists():
    blob_client.upload_blob("", overwrite=True)

# Load your DataFrame into a CSV file
csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)

# Upload the CSV file to the blob
blob_name = f"{folder_name}/your_csv_file.csv"
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name=blob_name)
blob_client.upload_blob(csv_data, overwrite=True)

print("DataFrame has been uploaded as a CSV file to the Azure Blob storage.")
```

I have the following information with me regarding an Azure storage account.

1. Storage account name
2. Container name
3. Key

   Now, I want to connect to this storage account and container and make a folder inside this container (If it doesn't exist) called Folder1 and store a dataframe as csv in it. Can anyone help me please on how to do this in python

I tried the code above but it seems to be outdated, Can anyone help me in correcting this ?

Comment: Please read [ask]. _Specifically_, what does "seems to be outdated" mean?

Answer (score 0):

> tried the code above but it seems to be outdated, Can anyone help me in correcting this ?

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as I used below code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pandas as pd

c = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwik;AccountKey=rCQR+OahVS0hT/C+AStNYbM6Q==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
cn= "rithwik"
bsc = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(c)
fn = "Folder1"
fbn = f"{fn}/"
fbc = bsc.get_blob_client(container=cn, blob=fbn)
if not fbc.exists():
    fbc.upload_blob("", overwrite=False)
f = "emo.csv"
bc = bsc.get_blob_client(container=cn, blob=f"{fn}/{f}")
d = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Rithwik","Bojja"], "From": ["Hyderabad", "India"]})
d.to_csv(f, index=False)
with open(f, "rb") as info:
    bc.upload_blob(info)
```

Here c is connection string

cn is container name

f is filename you want to give

fn is folder name

[image]

When I execute the above code, In storage account i get folder and file created as below:

[image]

[image]

Then i executed again with another filename then 2nd file got  created:

[image]